# getting input from user in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 10
#define TEMPSIZE 1024

int DiagSum(int **p, int sizearray) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizearray; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizearray; j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                sum = sum + p[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int SizeArray(int **p) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TEMPSIZE; i++) {
        if (p[i] == ' ' || p[i]=='\t')
            i++;
    }
    return p[i];
}
void main() {
    int **p;
    int input;
    int sizear=0;
    int i, j, counter = 0;

    p = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        p[j] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF || input != '\n') {
        if (input == ' ' || input == '\t')
            continue;
        input = input - '0';
        sizear = SizeArray(p);
        for (i = 0; i < sizear; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < sizear; j++)
            {
                p[i][j] = input - '0';
                counter++;
            }
        }
    if (counter > sizear*sizear) {
        printf("you've entered too many numbers \n");
    }
    else if (counter < sizear*sizear) {
        printf("you've entered not enough numbers \n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < sizear; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizear; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", p[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

COMPLETELY stuck. My assignment asks me to get input from user, only one line. It will consist of the size of the matrix (n*n) and that would be the first number in that line, and the numbers that will be in it. for example: 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. 3 (first number)-rows and column, the numbers follow will be the numbers inside the matrix. First mistake and most important is not being able to extract that first number that would be the array size, second is probably the bad input into the matrix. How should I fix it?

Comment: Why do you use dynamic allocation if you use static size (`N`) ?

Comment: @Stargateur That was our instructor recommendation. N is just a temporary number that indicate the max size of the array.

Comment: `SizeArray` checks `p[i] == ' '` where `p` is a 2 dimensional array of integers. `p[i]` cannot be compared to `char`

Comment: why you return `return p[i]` ? which always gives you some big number because it refers to some address. if can calculate `sizeof 2d array` like this `int sizeear = sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]);`

Comment: `int main`. `||` -> `&&` in the loop expression!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define TEMPSIZE 1024

int DiagSum(int **p, int sizearray) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizearray; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizearray; j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                sum = sum + p[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void main() {
    int **p;
    char input[TEMPSIZE] = {0};
    int sizear=0;
    int i, j, counter = 0;

    //get input string(size no more than 1024)
    fgets(input, TEMPSIZE, stdin);

    //get array size
    char* str = strstr(input, " ");
    if(str == 0)
    return;
    str[0] = 0;
    str++;
    sizear = atoi(input);

    if(sizear <= 0)
    return;

    //create array
    p = (int**)calloc(sizear, sizeof(int*));
    for (j = 0; j < sizear; j++)
    {
        p[j] = (int*)calloc(sizear, sizeof(int));
    }

    //fill array with input
    for (i = 0; i < sizear; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizear; j++)
        {
            char* temp = strstr(str, " ");
            if(temp == 0)
            {
                p[i][j] = atoi(str);
                counter++;
                goto end;
            }
            temp[0] = 0;
            p[i][j] = atoi(str);
            str = temp + 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }

end:
    if (counter > sizear*sizear) {
        printf("you've entered too many numbers \n");
    }
    else if (counter < sizear*sizear) {
        printf("you've entered not enough numbers \n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < sizear; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizear; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //free memory
    for (j = 0; j < sizear; j++)
    {
        free(p[j]);
    } 
    free(p);
}
```

I think above code will help you!

Comment: Thanks! you saved me!

Comment: Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` + `memset`. Do not cast the return value of `malloc`. There is no `gets` in the C standard!!!